# How to retrieve one random row for each category?

Tags: mysql

I would like to retrieve one random row for each user_group. How can I do this ?

Here find **2 tables**, user and user_group.

user :

```
id
firstname
user_group_id
```

user_group :

```
id
label
```

**Data**

users

```
1 | Thor        | 1
2 | Iron man    | 2
3 | Hulk        | 3
4 | Groot       | 3
```

user_groups

```
1 | admin
2 | support
3 | user
```

**Results expected**

```
1 | Thor        | admin
2 | Iron man    | support
4 | Groot       | user (or 3 | Hulk | user)
```

Comment: I edited my answer so it should work in default mode for MySQL 5.7. @Z0om

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer using GROUP BY will conflict with the default SQL mode in MySQL 5.7 and later, which makes it an error to reference columns in the select-list that are neither in the GROUP BY, nor in an aggregate function.

The solution in MySQL 8.0 is to use window functions:

```
SELECT r.id, r.firstname, r.user_group_id, g.label
FROM (
  SELECT id, firstname, user_group_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_group_id ORDER BY RAND()) AS rownum
  FROM users
) AS r
JOIN user_groups AS g ON (r.user_group_id = g.id)
WHERE r.rownum = 1
```

---

Re your comment:

```
SELECT r.id, r.firstname, r.user_group_id, r.count, g.label
FROM (
  SELECT id, firstname, user_group_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_group_id ORDER BY RAND()) AS rownum,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_group_id) AS count
  FROM users
) AS r
JOIN user_groups AS g ON (r.user_group_id = g.id)
WHERE r.rownum = 1
```

Result:

```
+------+-----------+---------------+-------+---------+
| id   | firstname | user_group_id | count | label   |
+------+-----------+---------------+-------+---------+
|    1 | Thor      |             1 |     1 | admin   |
|    2 | Iron Man  |             2 |     1 | support |
|    3 | Hulk      |             3 |     2 | user    |
+------+-----------+---------------+-------+---------+
```

You can use aggregate functions over windows. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html for details on this.

Comment: You 're right, the previous anwser doesn't work with MySQL 5.7 but yours too :(

Comment: Finaly, you ve got the solution for me. Thanks a lot !

Comment: One more thing. If I want the number of users by user_group_id. Is it possible ? By adding a `count(*)`, it broke the expected result (one row returned)

`SELECT r.id, r.firstname, r.user_group_id, g.label
FROM (
  SELECT id, firstname, user_group_id, c
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_group_id ORDER BY RAND()) AS rownum
  FROM users
) AS r
JOIN user_groups AS g ON (r.user_group_id = g.id)
WHERE r.rownum = 1`

Answer (score 1):

A solution that can work with MySQL 5.7 and later

You can create a temporary table from `users` using `ORDER BY rand()` to order your users randomly.

Then you can user `GROUP BY` with `ANY_VALUE()` in that temporary table to get the id of a random user from that group and just `JOIN` with your tables to get the other data you want.

You can see a working example here:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jtjPDxFVyzh4zGjXNbLAiL/5

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tbl
SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY rand() ;

SELECT u.id,u.firstname,g.label FROM 
(
SELECT ANY_VALUE(id) AS id FROM temp_tbl GROUP BY user_group_id
) t 
INNER JOIN `users` u ON t.id=u.id
INNER JOIN `user_groups` g ON g.id=u.user_group_id
```

Comment: I dont want to use a temporary table.

Comment: @z0om I am just trying to provide a solution that works in MySQL 5.7 A solution that works in MySQL 8.0 is already given in other answers...